# Call colorbox from button onclick

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

Good evning. I'm using Colorbox and I have a question: For example, I have a colorbox images list from 1 to 10.

How can I open a Colorbox with start image is picture number 5/10 by click on a different button ?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
$('a').eq(5).click();
```

Just select the a-tag that you usually click for image 5 and trigger a click on it.

Comment: Thanks. I have images 1..241, so a bit broader problem. Made some intermediate jumps, with a single-argument function comprising your one-liner, slightly modified: `$('a.gal').eq(num - 1).click();` since the image list is 0-based.